# Matlab Printing/Rendering Issue: Dotted Diagonal Line Prints Across Rectangle

Tags: matlab, pdf, printing

A dotted diagonal line appears when I print any annotation rectangle in MATLAB.

Example of Issue:

[image]

I am attempting to create a annotation rectangle with black face color of arbitrary size on a figure.  In the MATLAB figure window, everything displays properly.  When I print the figure to a pdf, a diagonal dashed line appears from the bottom left corner to the top right corner.  I don't want this line to appear and would like your assistance in removing it from my pdf outputs.

---

## Code:

```
h = figure( 'Units', 'inches', 'Position', [0 0 11 8.5], ...
    'PaperPosition', [0 0 11 8.5], 'PaperOrientation', 'landscape', 'Resize', ...
    'off','Visible','on', 'Renderer', 'painters');

a = annotation('rectangle','Linestyle', 'none', 'Units', 'inches', ...
    'Position', [.25 .25 .5 .5], ...
    'FaceColor', 'k', 'EdgeColor', 'none');

print(h,'temp.pdf','-dpdf','-r600', '-painters');
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it an option to save it as `png` instead? The diagonal line seems to appear only in pdf.
And for me the line is from top left to bottom right...

Comment: @ThijsW Unfortunately I need to save as a pdf.  I have seen the diagonal appear in both directions.  Also, I tried to use the "-zbuffer" option with the print command, which gets rid of the diagonal line but makes all the text on the page look terrible.

Comment: I have tried some different renderers too. `'-zbuffer'` removes the diagonal line for me, but adds about ten vertical lines to the rectangle. I think `'-opengl'` was the same, have you tried that one? It does seem to be a renderer problem, but I'm afraid there's only these three options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is not the output from the matlab renderer, but settings of the PDF viewer. Perhaps you can try changing some settings in the PDF viewer, particularly the settings for anti-aliasing.

I tried opening the pdf file created using your code in an online PDF viewer and the diagonal line was gone.

Another workaround might be to save as `.eps` instead, and convert the eps file to pdf.

source: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280185

Comment: Great, I hadn't considered that.  In the preferences menu of Acrobat Reader, under the "Page Display" tab, Disabling "smooth line art" made the issue go away. Thanks! (Don't have the reputation to vote up yet or I would)